# Get both results with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get results for likes by a specific user-id and all likes and dislikes of a specific page id.

My structure looks like this:

```
`pages`: (id, title)
`pages_likes`: (id, page_id, uid, status)
```

If the `status` is `-1` it's a dislike of a specific page, if it's `1` it's a like.

So, to get all likes this is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pages_likes WHERE status = '1'
```

But now I also want to get if user-id 3 for example likes this page with

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pages_likes WHERE status = '1' AND uid='3'
```

How can I achieve both in one query? I guess there has to be changed something right after the SELECT statement?

Comment: Sorry, just added a new information to my question I forgot to mention. Please refresh it.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Something like: `likes`: 19 `userlike`: 1 (true), `dislikes`: 3, `userdislike`: 0 (false). I prefer the answer of Tim Biegeleisen, but I want to include the option to have the dislikes and dislike by the specific user of this specific page too. @sgeddes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in a single query, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN uid = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS threeLikes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid <> '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS otherLikes
FROM pages_likes
WHERE status = '1'
```

Another option would be to use a `UNION`, cf. the answer given by @bernie

**Update:**

If you want page likes *and* dislikes in the same query, you can try:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN uid = '3'  AND status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS threeLikes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid <> '3' AND status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS otherLikes
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid = '3'  AND status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS threeDislikes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid <> '3' AND status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS otherDisikes
FROM pages_likes
```

Comment: Better answer than mine! +1

Comment: How would the query look like if I want to get dislikes of that user and page_id in general too? By the way, isn't it more efficient to do all this in one query instead of writing two? Because you said "If you want to do this in a single query".

Comment: @Vaia It's not desirable to keep going back and forth.  If you want specific output, then just come out and tell us exactly what you want in the beginning.  The answer to your new question: yes, this can be done by just adding new conditional aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT '' user, COUNT(id) likes 
FROM pages_likes 
WHERE status = '1' 
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL

SELECT uid user, COUNT(id) likes 
FROM pages_likes 
WHERE status = '1' AND uid='3'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_likes, SUM(uid=3) AS uid3_likes
FROM pages_likes
WHERE status=1 AND page_id=1234
```

Re your comment:

Here's an example of showing total likes, and total dislikes. It's similar to the answer from @TimBiegeleisen.

```
SELECT SUM(status=1) AS total_likes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid=3 AND status=1 THEN 1 END) AS uid3_likes
       SUM(CASE WHEN uid=3 AND status=-1 THEN 1 END) AS uid3_dislikes
FROM pages_likes
WHERE page_id=1234
```

Comment: How would the query look like if I want to get dislikes of that user and page_id in general too?